# How to call grpc service in openshift from java

Tags: java, openshift, grpc, minishift

I have a client and a service with gRPC. Locally they work well. I tried to start the server in openshift (minishift):

```yaml
kind: DeploymentConfig
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: app-grpc
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        app: app-grpc
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: app-grpc
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: app-grpc
              ports:
                - containerPort: 9005
                  protocol: TCP
              imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: Always
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst

---
kind: Service
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "app-grpc-service"
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9005
      targetPort: 9005
  selector:
    app: "app-grpc"

---
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: "app-grpc-route"
spec:
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: app-grpc-service
```

But the call from the client does not reach the server.
I am not sure if I have configured Service and Route correctly

The client looks like this:

```java
ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder
    .forAddress("app-grpc-route-myproject.111.111.111.111.nip.io/app-grpc", 9005)
    .usePlaintext()
    .build();

try {
    HelloServiceGrpc.HelloServiceBlockingStub client = HelloServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    System.out.println(client.hello(HelloRequest.newBuilder()
        .setFirstName("firstName")
        .setLastName("lastName")
        .build())
        .getGreeting());
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    channel.shutdown();
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm specifying host correctly. I copied it from route.

When trying to call
`forAddress("app-grpc-route-myproject.111.111.111.111.nip.io", 9005)`I have `Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information`

If I use `.forAddress("app-grpc-route-myproject.111.111.111.111.nip.io/app-grpc", 9005)` I have `Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception: First received frame was not SETTINGS. Hex dump for first 5 bytes: 485454502f`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to serve gRPC connections, you need your ingress controller to handle HTTP2 connections.

[This is not the case by default](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/networking/ingress-operator.html#nw-http2-haproxy_configuring-ingress).

So, your answer might be to enter the following command:

```
oc annotate ingresses.config/cluster ingress.operator.openshift.io/default-enable-http2=true
```